# Bash loop script for incremental files

Tags: linux, bash

wrote a bash script to create empty files a certain times when executed. After the first execution, it returns a syntax error & seems to infinitely execute. Please what is my error?

```sh
/bin/bash
#Create loop for incremental files

counter=1
if (ls -f sam*.txt)2>/dev/null;
then
        max=$(ls -F sam*.txt)
        while ((counter<=5))
        do
              ((max++))
              touch sam$max.txt
              ((counter))
        done
else
        touch sam{1..10}.txt
fi
```

Comment: You are missing `#!` before `/bin/bash` (probably a typo). Your logic is hard to follow. You test if there are no `sam*.txt` files, and only then ask for `max=` (which would be zero if you made it there). Better `numsam=$(ls -1 same*txt 2>/dev/null | wc -l)` then`max="$numsam"`. Then you can enter your `while` loop. Your use of `touch sam{1..10}.txt` is fine if there are no sam files

Answer (score 0):

As I read this, if your files exist, they will always start with `sam1.txt`, so I'd test for that first.

```
if [[ -e sam1.txt ]]; then
```

This means `sam*.txt` files do exist. If you don't want to trust that `sam1.txt` will always exist if any do, then assign to an array and test for element zero.

```
sam=( sam*.txt )
if [[ -e "${sam[0]}" ]]; then
```

If no files exist, element zero will *probably* (depending on options you might have set) be `sam*.txt`, which could exist as a valid filename, but if it does, you still get a hit that a file exist.

Your assignment to `max` is almost certainly not what you want.

```
$: max=$(ls -F sam*.txt)
$: ((max++));
bash: ((: -rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 
sam1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam3.txt: 
syntax error in expression (error token is "r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam3.txt")
```

What you want will already be present if you use the array & files existed though. `${#sam[@]}` is the number of elements in `sam`.

```
$: sam=( sam*.txt )
$: if [[ -e "${sam[0]}" ]]; then
>    echo "${#sam[@]} files: ${sam[@]}"
>  fi
3 files: sam1.txt sam2.txt sam3.txt
```

`max` is serving no useful prupose, by the way.
So,

```
sam=( sam*.txt )
if [[ -e "${sam[0]}" ]]; then    
  cnt=${#sam[@]}
  while (( ++cnt <= 5 )); do touch sam$cnt.txt; done
else touch sam{1..10}.txt
fi
```

Run when `sam1.txt`, `sam2.txt`, & `sam3.txt` exist, it adds 4 & 5.

```
$: ls -l sam*txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:27 sam3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:40 sam4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jun 23 09:40 sam5.txt
```

Clear them and run when they don't, it creates 1-10.

Is that what you wanted?